# Closed Form Solution to Binomial Sum with Log

Tags: summation, logarithms, closed-form, binomial-distribution

I am wondering if there is a closed form expression for

$\sum_{s=0}^N {N\choose s} q^s(1-q)^{N-s}\ln[x+s(y-x)/N]-\sum_{s=0}^{N-1} {N-1\choose s} q^s(1-q)^{N-1-s}\ln[x+s(y-x)/N]$

where y>x>0 are some constants. Any help is greatly appreciated.

More specifically, I want to show that this expression is decreasing in N (which I am able to verify numerically).

Comment: In the ln which is in the sum, is it $x+s/(N(y-x))$ or $x+s(y-x)/N$?

Comment: The second. Just edited it.